# MAC 10.4.11 & Win2k8

Tags: mac-osx, mac, kerberos

I am attempting to use a Mac Xserve running 10.4.11 to access a file share on a Win2k8 machine, but it's failing due to Kerberos authentication errors.  Any ideas how to fix/update a Mac?

As an aside, this is the first Mac I've dealt with in 20 years, so it's all new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Most common cause of Kerberos errors is time drift between the two boxes. Ensure they both have the same time and time zone.

If that's correct a look at [this forum thread](http://www.chicagotech.net/netforums/viewtopic.php?t=4578&sid=85c5f48e8552283becfa356c9c34096) might help.

Comment: I would prefer a resolution to this that did not lower security on my win2k8 boxes.  An interesting read nonetheless.